# Finding subsets of a set of vectors that fulfill some conditions

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

After all the reviews that I had for this question, I have made changes to make it clearer and simpler.

To solve this problem, I have a matrix `A` and a row vector `A(1,2:7)` (row reference) which contains at least one `0`.

From the matrix `A`:

```
A=[1   2 0 1 2 0 0   0
   2   1 1 1 0 2 2   0
   3   0 0 0 0 1 1   1
   4   0 2 0 1 1 1   2
   5   0 0 0 0 0 1   0
   6   1 0 1 1 2 0   2
   7   1 1 2 2 2 1   1
   8   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
   9   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
  10   2 2 2 2 0 0   1]
```

**I want to find one or if possible all combinations of vectors `A(k,2:7),k≠1 and A(k,8)=0`, in addition to `A(1,2:7)`,  which satisfy the following conditions:**

1. The combination is formed only with the vectors that satisfy 
   `A(k,8)=0; k=1,..,10`
2. I will not consider A(7,2:7) in the results since it does not contain any 0.
3. if `{A(1,2:7),A(j,2:7)}` is a given combination, this mean that
   at less `A(1,n)≠0` or `A(j,n)≠0` for `n = 2,...,7`. (at least one of
   the two values that are on the same column in `A`, should be
   different from `0`)
4. One combination can contain two or more vectors. Another example:
   if `{A(1,2:7),A(j,2:7),A(p,2:7)}` is a given combination, this mean
   that at less `A(1,n)≠0` or `A(j,n)≠0` or `A(p,n)≠0` for `n =
   2,...,7`. (at least one of the three values that are on the same
   column in `A`, should be different from `0`)
5. For the matrix `A`, `{A(1,2:7),A(2,2:7)}` is a combination that
   satisfies the desired conditions. But I do not want to have a
   combination such `{A(1,2:7),A(2,2:7),A(3,2:7)}` since `A(1,2:7)` and
   `A(2,2:7)` are sufficient to form one combination.

For the combination of vectors, I must take one vector as a reference, in this case it is the vector `A(1,2:7)`. This is the vector we want to compensate their zeros. So `A(1,2:7)` contributes in the association by its nonzero components:2,1 and 2.

when I say above "I want to find ... in addition to `A(1,2:7)`", this is valid when `A(1,2:7)` is the row reference. But if `A(5,2:7)` is the row reference, in this case the sentence becomes "in addition to `A(5,2:7)`".

**For my real problem `A` is a `700x8` matrix. Here `A` , `A(1,2:7)` and `A(7,2:7)` are just an example, I prefer a solution for Any vector `A(k,2:7)` of the matrix `A`, with `A(k,8)=0` and at least one of its components is `0`.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67051/discussion-between-knedlsepp-and-bzak).

Comment: I really wonder why people are voting this question negatively !!!

Comment: Because it was (and still is) written in a very confusing manner.

Comment: @knedlsepp: where is exactly the problem?

Comment: Even though you say you made *it clearer and simpler*, you just made it longer. By the way: It is a **very bad idea** to change your question in a way, that changes the original intent.
If you keep changing what you are asking for, nobody will want to try to answer it.
You should only make changes to the question to make it clearer what you are asking, not to change WHAT you are asking for. Also: I already told you that this whole (2:6) business is only making it more complicated, than it needs to be.
Also: What is your question?

Comment: @knedlsepp: I changed my question only because I have not received an answer. And since you said that the result requires an enormous time, so I tried to change my question to make it reasonable for the computation time and suitable to my needs. for (2:6), it was just to make my question easy to understand. but I can call A(:,2:6)=B. My question is just after the matrix A.

Comment: I get that, but it may have been better to start a fresh question where you boil down your question to something like that: "Given a matrix B containing `0`s, `1`s and `2`s.[Forget about your first and last row for the moment] For a selected row `i`, I want to find a set of rows `R_i`, in a way that 1.) it includes `i`, 2.) for all columns there is at least one row, whose column-entry is not zero. Also this set `R_i` should be as small as possible". [Forget about your way of scoring those sets. You should make this work first anyway. Then you can ask another question about scoring.]

Comment: Divide what you want to achieve into smaller subproblems, that are not connected. So you can ask multiple questions that **don't** contain: "In addition to my last question I also want...."

Comment: What do you want to do in a combination containing `A(2,2:6), A(3,2:6)  and A(4,2:6)`? Both `A(2,3)` and `A(4,3)` contribute to cover the zero in `A(3,3)`. Do you count the first one only? Both? The one that has the 1?

Comment: Man, how did you come up with that last column? Are you sure you mean `A(k,7)=0`, or did you mean `A(k,8)=0`, because that last column is column 8.

Comment: @beaker: I would have liked to find all the possible combinations, but I've edited my question to have only one combination, but which satisfies the condition 7. Indeed, I had made a mistake in my question. it is A(k,8)=0 and not A(k,7)=0. I am sincerely sorry for my bad question!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve. This question is written in such a way that it feels like you are asking us to solve your problem in a specific (strange) way rather than asking for help to solve it in general. -- For a while I thought you were looking for a base, but some of the question conflicts that again.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: it's just a small part of my big problem I am trying to solve here! My question may sound strange, unfortunately this is the path I must follow to reach my goal!!!

Comment: This question is being either closed or forgotten as soon as the bounty time expires. If you want more people to answer, consider reformulating it and/or breaking it down in several parts (questions).

Comment: As now some time has passed: Have you had a look at: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29650-greedy-algorithm-for-set-cover-problem ?

Comment: The sufficient condition is not clear. You need to elaborate.

Comment: @OlegKomarov: I mean in this case that A(1,2:7) and A(2,2:7) are sufficient to form one combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit complicated and hard to follow.. Anyways I tried writing some code to the best of my understanding of the problem. Here is the part that finds the possible combinations:

```
% input matrix
A=[1   2 0 1 2 0 0   0
   2   1 1 1 0 2 2   0
   3   0 0 0 0 1 1   1
   4   0 2 0 1 1 1   2
   5   0 0 0 0 0 1   0
   6   1 0 1 1 2 0   2
   7   1 1 2 2 2 1   1
   8   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
   9   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
  10   2 2 2 2 0 0   1];

% start by considering all rows
rowsIndices = (1:size(A,1))';
rIdx = true(size(rowsIndices));

% exclude 7th row (i.e rows with no zeros in columns 2:7)
%idx(~any(A(:,2:7)==0,2)) = false;
rIdx(7) = false;

% exclude rows that dont have zero in column 8
rIdx(A(:,8) ~= 0) = false;

% for each possible n-combinations
N = sum(rIdx);
combs = cell(1,N);
for k=2:N
    % all combinations of k-rows
    combsK = nchoosek(rowsIndices(rIdx), k);

    % must involve first row
    combsK = combsK(any(combsK==1,2),:);

    % exclude from current k-combinations if there are smaller ones
    if k > 2
        combsKIdx = true(size(combsK,1),1);
        for kk=2:k-1
            if isempty(combs{kk}), continue, end
            for i=1:size(combs{kk},1)
                combsKIdx(sum(ismember(combsK,combs{kk}(i,:)),2)==kk) = false;
            end
        end
        combsK = combsK(combsKIdx,:);
    end

    % for every possible combination, each column 2:7 must not be all zeros
    combsKIdx = true(size(combsK,1),1);
    for i=1:size(combsK,1)
        combsKIdx(i) = all(any(A(combsK(i,:),2:7),1));
    end
    combsK = combsK(combsKIdx,:);

    % store combinations found
    combs{k} = combsK;
end

% display results
celldisp(combs)
```

Here are the combinations I got:

```
combs{1} =
     []
combs{2} =
     1     2
combs{3} =
     1     5     8
     1     5     9
combs{4} =
     []
combs{5} =
     []
```

in other words three combinations; first with rows [1 2], second [1 5 8], and third with rows [1 5 9].

The part I left out is the final step of computing the "scores" of each combination found. Honestly I didn't understand how, the description was confusing! So I'll leave that part to you..

Comment: @bzak: ok I've updated my answer based on that. Is it giving the expected results? Obviously you still have to do the contribution-scores part (I'm still not sure how you computed that).

Comment: @Amro: kudos for giving this a go!

Comment: @bzak: I've got a few questions for you. First, have you changed your requirement that you want to find combinations that must involve `A(1,2:7)` (that's what it says in the statement in bold)? Your examples suggest otherwise! Second, you went back to using columns `2:6` instead of `2:7`, which is it now? Third, assuming you found a combination, how do you know which one is the reference vector? Finally, I still dont understand what you mean by `associate the value i+10 to the vector that contributes by at least one 1, and value i to the vector which contributes only by values equal to 2`?

Comment: @Amro: 1-I have not changed my requirements, It's just that I forgot to mention that this was just an example to facilitate understanding my question, and that any vector can be chosen. 2- I always work with 2:7, it is a mistake, sorry! 3- The reference vector is the vector I initially chose to compensate theirs zeros. 4- For a vector Vi (i: row index), In the final result, I replace Vi by the value i+10 if Vi contributes by at least one 1 in the combinaison to balance the presence of 0 in the reference vector, and I replace Vi by the value i if Vi contributes only by values equal to 2.

Comment: @Amro: I underestimated your answer :)

Comment: @Amro: This line is not necessary, and can be deleted: % must involve first row
    combsK = combsK(any(combsK==1,2),:);

Comment: @Amro: Please, Why combs{3} result is different in these two cases: "1" if I do the calculation for k = 2:3. "2" if I do the calculation only for k = 3 (for k = 3:3 )

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly understood the mind-bogglingly overcomplicated description of the requirements that was here, you want:

- the minimal set of rows including one particular reference row
- which all have a zero in the last column, and at least one zero in the 'data' columns
- such that the set of rows together contain at least one nonzero element in every 'data' column

  - and then do some fiddling about with the resulting indices

Since I happen to have spent the last couple of days working on something similar, this is good and fresh. Here's a simple brute-force approach - if efficiency with larger data is a concern, generating all the combinations up front needs to be replaced (I ended up writing a recursive iterator which calls a callback function for each combination, but I'll leave that out for simplicity here). I've assumed that the first column will always contain the relevant original indices as per the example - this makes it really easy to pull the data apart without losing track, and pulling the data apart helps simplify the logic somewhat.

Example setup:

```
A=[1   2 0 1 2 0 0   0
   2   1 1 1 0 2 2   0
   3   0 0 0 0 1 1   1
   4   0 2 0 1 1 1   2
   5   0 0 0 0 0 1   0
   6   1 0 1 1 2 0   2
   7   1 1 2 2 2 1   1
   8   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
   9   0 1 1 2 2 0   0
  10   2 2 2 2 0 0   1];
% data columns
colidx = 2:7;
% reference row
refidx = 1;
indices = findindices(A, refidx, colidx)
% then muck about with the indices as need be
```

Functions:

```
function indices = findindices(A, refidx, colidx)
% pick out the relevant rows
setidx = (A(:,8) == 0) & ~all(A(:,colidx), 2) & (A(:,1) ~= refidx);
ref = A(refidx, :);
rows = A(setidx, :);
% no need to pass any more than the columns of interest here
c = findcombination(ref(colidx), rows(:,colidx));
% turn the combination of 'rows' indices back into the original ones,
indices = [ref(1); rows(c, 1)];
end

function c = findcombination(ref, rows)
n = size(rows, 1);
% search all 1-combinations first, then 2-combinations, etc.
% to ensure we find the smallest first.
for k=1:n
    for c = nchoosek(1:n, k)'
        set = [ref; rows(c,:)];
        if any(set, 1) % true if all columns have at least one nonzero
            return;   % c contains the combination in terms of the rows array
        end
    end
end
c = [];
error('no valid combination!')
end
```

And the result for the example data:

```
>> test

indices =

    1
    2
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! Can I put in your program "refidx = p;" to make it valid for other references row?

Comment: what I have to change if I want A(5,2:7) as the reference row?

Comment: findindices(A,5,2:7) gives:  ??? Error using ==> findindices>findcombination at 26
no valid combination!

Error in ==> findindices at 7
c = findcombination(ref(colidx), rows(:,colidx));

Error in ==> Filter at 18
indices = findindices(A, refidx, colidx)

Comment: findindices(A,5,2:7) gives: indices = 15 11 12. while this is not a good result! as 11 12 is a sufficient combination

Comment: "I want to find one combination of vectors A(k,2:7),k≠1 and A(k,8)=0, _in addition to A(1,2:7)_" implies to me that you wanted the reference row (1) to explicitly be included in the set, hence the interpretation I listed at the top of the answer. If my interpretation is wrong, please try to specify the conditions more generally with less confusingly-specific details.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!  "in addition to A(1,2:7)" is valid when A(1,2:7) is the row reference. But when A(5,2:7) is the row reference, in this case the sentence becomes "in addition to A(5,2:7)".